# Particular Migration Script via Controller Symfony2

Tags: symfony

In Symfony2 application, I am trying to run migration script via controller as below :

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class SpoolController extends Controller
{
    public function migrateAction($entity_manager = 'default')
    {
        $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        $input = new ArrayInput(array(
           'command' => 'doctrine:migrations:migrate',
           '--em' => $entity_manager,
        ));
        // You can use NullOutput() if you don't need the output
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);

        // return the output, don't use if you used NullOutput()
        $content = $output->fetch();

        // return new Response(""), if you used NullOutput()
        return new Response($content);
    }
}
```

Above code is working when I do not specify migration script name in the command. But when I specify version number in the command as below :

```
$input = new ArrayInput(array(
       'command' => 'doctrine:migrations:migrate 20150916202248',
       '--em' => 'codes',
));
```

then I am getting error :

> string '[InvalidArgumentException] Command
>   "doctrine:migrations:migrate 20150916202248" is not defined. Did you
>   mean one of these? doctrine:migrations:status doctrine:migrations:diff
>   doctrine:migrations:execute '... (length=880)

**Is it not possible to run particular version file via controller?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
$input = new ArrayInput(array(
   'command' => 'doctrine:migrations:migrate',
   '' => '20150916202248',
   '--em' => 'codes',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add Argument with the specific function?

```
/.../

 $input = new ArrayInput([
       'command' => 'doctrine:migrations:migrate',
       '--em' => $entity_manager,
 ]);

 $input->addArgument('version', '20150916202248'); 

 /.../
```

**EDIT**

It seems to be this kind of solution:

```
/.../

$input = new ArrayInput([
      'command' => 'doctrine:migrations:migrate',
      'version' => '20150916202248',
      '--em' => $entity_manager,
]);

/.../
```

Comment: I am getting error as `Error: Call to private method Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput::addArgument() from context 'AcmeBundle\Controller\SpoolController'`